# iPhone app compiled with Xcode 6 on runs as Universal on iPad

Tags: ipad, ios8, xcode6

I have got an app developed for iPhone family only, and I used to run it on iPad to test how it will look on iPhone 4s (since it launched with iPhone 4s resolution, size, and else '2x' round button for fullscreen support). However, now when I run it on my iPad with iOS 8, Xcode ignores all build settings and runs it as for iPad. My storyboard constraints were not projected for iPad screen.

I have:

1. `Devices` option set to `iPhone` on General tab in project settings
2. `Main storyboard file name` and `Main storyboard file name` are removed from `Info-plist`
3. All App Icons and Launch Images for iPad are deleted
4. In `Launch Screen File` the option `Use Size Classes` set to `NO`, and the assets are generated for iPhone only

Is that a normal behavior? I want to use my iPad as before to test iPhone 4s resolution. I am sure that my app won't become universal because of that, but nevertheless I think this is a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of `Launch Screen File` in iOS 8.0, 8.0.1 and 8.0.2 will make you universal.

This is a know bug and fixed in iOS 8.1, for you only option is to use assets catalog with a launch images.

Or you can add the device modifier in the Launch file name, like `<launchNib>~iphone.nib`

Comment: that is very sad, I've already get very satisfied with this instrument. Thank you, it solved the problem. Can you also provide any links with a little more detail on that issue?

Comment: Yes, there is on open radar: http://openradar.io/18371031 It even has a solution that I did know about.