# Ipad with IOS8 running iphone app in ipad size

Tags: ipad, ios8, xcode6

I have created a sample iphone application Xcode 6 with ios8 comptability.when i run the application in ipad it is running in Ipad size not iphone size.but i have developed only iphone application not universal.

Thanks & Regards
Sam.P

Comment: i'm experiencing this same exact issue

Comment: Yes sogwiz..that is ios8 issue we cant do anything for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution may be found in the following stack overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26280780/824202

Keep your "Launch Screen File" empty and it should work.  This fixed the issue for me. [image]