# 2.10 iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

My APP was rejected，Because follow issue.
----- 2.10 -----

We also found that your app did not meet the requirements for running on iPad, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

Your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad. While your app may be built for iPhone or iPod, it must still run on iPad, at iPhone resolution and at 2x iPhone 3GS resolution.

---

My app shows iPad model in iPad IOS8 version.but i want the app that shows iPhone 2x model in iPad.
it shows iPhone model in iPad before iOS7.1 version.
how to show iPhone model in iPad iOS 8 version.

Comment: What does your app currently do when run on an iPad?

Comment: I want to show iPhone view 2X in ipad

Comment: Have you specified a storyboard as your launch image?  There is a bug that prevents iPhone apps operating correctly in this case - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26280652/iphone-app-compiled-with-xcode-6-on-runs-as-universal-on-ipad

Comment: thank you.yes I have set a storyboard as launch image.I deleted the xib file to fixed successfully @Paulw11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deleting the Launch Screen File in XCode 6.use Launch image

Comment: Think you could elaborate on this? I'm having this same problem....my app is supposed to be iPhone only, I'm really confused.

Comment: Did you resolve the problem？

Comment: Not yet....ended up hiring a more experienced iOS developer to do it out of frustration, he hasn't fixed it yet either.

Comment: deleting the Launch Screen xib File.is this still can't help you?

Comment: I  have same issue.. I am using Launch Image in Launch image sources , still I need to delete Launch Screen file???

Comment: @DeviPhone26 You can try unchecking" use size classes "

Comment: @AllanXing  Ok Thanks I will try with this.