# rejected by 2.10 iPhone Apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, launch-screen

My app was rejected by apple , they told me this message:

> We noticed that your app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad
> running iOS 9.2.1, which is a violation of the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, the app only displayed a white screen after launching on iPad.
>
> We’ve attached screenshot(s) for your reference.

they show me the screen shot here [share photo](http://share.pho.to/A3nBg)

I want to repair this problem , but in my simulator and iPad device it works all fine .

I was rejected twice ， last time I not modify anything and submit again that was passed .

This time it rejected again , I find this QAF [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540357](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540357/2-10-iphone-apps-must-also-run-on-ipad-without-modification-at-iphone-resolutio/26544796#26544796) , and try to modify , but I don't know it's suit for me
, could anyone help repair mistake with my app ?

I have already delete Launch screen xib and uncheck " use size classes " .

Anything should I will do ?

ps: I added info.plist screen shot at pho.to/A3nOg/2o and general setting screen at pho.to/A3nOg/x2

Comment: Have you added brand assets?

Comment: check this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1780/_index.html

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan yes , I added a images.xcassets include icon images and Launch images

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan thanks for your suggest , In my app there not a file like  "MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard" , only one named "main.storyboard",I added setting and info.plist screen shot , please upgrade the question.thank you .